# Describing Bijections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question that asks: 
"Describe bijections $f$ : $(A\times B) \times C \rightarrow (A\times B)\times C, A\times B \rightarrow B\times A$

I have no idea how to start, or precisely what the question wants: do I find some function explicitly, or state something else?

Comment: The wording of the problem seems off.  Are you certain that this is the **exact** wording with the **exact** symbols used?  Are these two separate problems, the one having domain and codomain $(A\times B)\times C$ and the other having domain $A\times B$ and codomain $B\times A$?  There are $(|A||B||C|)!$ possible bijections with domain and codomain $(A\times B)\times C$ where each of $A,B,C$ are finite sets (*and infinitely many bijections of course otherwise*) and $(|A||B|)!$ possible bijections with domain $A\times B$ and codomain $B\times A$.

Comment: It is hard to describe the set of bijections in more detail than just "It is the set of all bijections" or "It is the set of all functions which are simultaneously injective and surjective"...  There are some trivially obvious ones of course, such as the identity map for the first or the one where the entries are swapped in the second case, but without more detail I don't understand what you or the original author intend

Comment: They are two separate questions:

Comment: So 1:   Describe a bijection $(A\times B)\times C \rightarrow (A\times B) \times C $

Comment: The identity$~~~$

Answer (score 0):

for $((a,b), c) \in (A \times B) \times C$, define its value as $(a, (b,c))\in A \times (B \times C)$ (this is the intended set!, not the same set again...) (the map is just rebracketing). Show it is a bijection using the fundamental property of pairs $(a,b) = (c,d)$ iff $a = c \land b = d$.

For the other: reverse coordinates.

Comment: What makes you assume the first problem was written incorrectly (*apart from it being incredibly trivial...which to be fair so is the rewritten question*)?  Is this problem and its specific phrasing something you recognize from a specific book?

Comment: @JMoravitz My way it's a standard result needed to show associativity of cardinal multiplication, so it's actually useful, not just true.